# Manage cache of web browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, webforms

I am trying to avoid storing cache in browsers but still my applications url's are displayed in cache.

I have used following code in my page load method of master page for disabling browser cache:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

And also alternatively tried using meta tags in html page but still cache displaying in following browser path:
1.chrome://cache/
2.about:cache?storage=disk&context=

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid storing cache by doing below steps
1. Go to the `App_Start`
2.Click `FilterConfig` file.
3. In the file enter the below code

```
public class NoCacheResponseHeaderFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store,must-revalidate");
            actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT");
        }
    }
```

The above code will clear the browser cache when the browser are refreshed because it will invoke the filter method before the page renders.
Hope this helps.